# How do I create a multi-column constraint in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, schema

I know this is very simple, but how do I do this in plain SQL?

Comment: What sort of a constraint? A unique constraint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a unique constraint during table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (
    Col1 int NOT NULL,
    Col2 int NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (Col1, Col2)
)
```

After table creation:

```
ALTER TABLE T1 ADD UNIQUE (Col1, Col2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about check constraints?

```
alter table MyTable add constraint CC_Dates check (FromDate < ToDate)
```